# SDK Flutter exit code 66 after deleting cache and temp files

Tags: flutter, windows, dart, visual-studio-code, sdk

I'm using the SDK Flutter, delete 100Gb of cache files with cmd commands, finally execute the next commands without caution of the selected directories:

<---

```
del /f /s /q %systemdrive%\*.tmp
del /f /s /q %systemdrive%\*._mp
del /f /s /q %systemdrive%\*.log
del /f /s /q %systemdrive%\*.gid
del /f /s /q %systemdrive%\*.chk
del /f /s /q %systemdrive%\*.old
del /f /s /q %systemdrive%\recycled\*.*
del /f /s /q %windir%\*.bak
del /f /s /q %windir%\prefetch\*.*
rd /s /q %windir%\temp & md %windir%\temp
del /f /q %userprofile%\cookies\*.*
del /f /q %userprofile%\recent\*.*
del /f /s /q “%userprofile%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\*.*”
del /f /s /q “%userprofile%\Local Settings\Temp\*.*”
del /f /s /q “%userprofile%\recent\*.*”
```

--->

Now when try to create a new project (VSCode) fail the application build creation:

<---

```
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_application_1...
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Users\MauricioAlejandro\Documents\ProjectsFlutter\Apps\flutter_application_1".
pub get failed
command: "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\src\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:create",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\MauricioAlejandro\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 66
```

--->

I appreciate your time to support me to revert the actions. At the moment just tried to uninstall the packages of flutter and dart on vs code